# Understanding the cosine as a partial derivative.

Tags: trigonometry, partial-derivative, rotations

From the first chapter of Arfken's Mathematical Methods for physicists (rotation of the coordinate axis):

> To go on to three and, later, four dimensions, we find it convenient to use a more compact notation. Let
>   \begin{equation}
> x → x_1,
> \textbf{  }
> y → x_2
> \end{equation}
>
> \begin{equation}
> a_{11} = cos\phi,\textbf{ } a_{12} = sin\phi
> \end{equation}
>
> \begin{equation}
> a_{21} = −sin\phi, \textbf{ } a_{22} = cos\phi
> \end{equation}
>
> Then Eqs. become
>
> \begin{equation}
> x′_1 = a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2
> \end{equation}
>
> \begin{equation}
> x′_2 = a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2.
> \end{equation}
>
> The coefficient $a_{ij}$ may be interpreted as a direction cosine, the cosine of the angle between $x'_i$ and $x_j$ ; that is,

This is all good. Later, the book states:

> From the definition of $a_{ij}$ as the cosine of the angle between the positive $x′_i$ direction and the positive $x_j$ direction we may write (Cartesian coordinates):
>
> \begin{equation}
> a_{ij}=\frac{\partial x'_i}{\partial x_j}
> \end{equation}

Where did that come from? I can't find anything about the cosine as a partial derivative, and I don't see how that works.

Comment: Take the derivatives of the $x'_i$s from your two equations at the end of your first box.

Comment: @JohnDouma The derivatives with respect to what? I'm sorry, I can't see it. Thank you.

Comment: Start with $\frac{\partial x'_1}{\partial x_1}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma all is understood, thank you. However, is it possible to get $$a_{ij}=\frac{\partial x'_i}{\partial x_j}$$ from the general equation $$
x_i^{\prime}=\sum_{j=1}^2 a_{i j} x_j
$$ I mean without specifying the index numbers. I reach this step $$
\frac{\partial x_i^{\prime}}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^2 a_{i j} x_j\right)
$$ with no clue how to compute this to get $a_{ij} $

Comment: @Sha I thought I was losing my mind. I was thinking, I don't remember this but then I looked at the date. Yes, because each of the $x_j$ are independent so the other terms vanish when you take the derivative with respect to one of them and you are left with just the coefficient of $x_j$ which in this case is $a_{ij}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, it is an old post :). I do not get it, sorry. How to compute the derivative without expanding the summation? I do know how to proceed when I expand the summation; however, I am interested in proceeding without the summation expansion. My logic is: $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial x_i^{\prime}}{\partial x_j} & =\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^2 a_{i j} x_j\right) \\
& =\sum_{j=1}^2 \alpha_{i j} \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_j}=\sum_{j=1}^2 a_{i j}
\end{aligned}
$$ which is not the result we are looking for.

Comment: @Sha I don't see how it gets easier than that. To expand the derivative the way you did exploits the linearity of the derivative. There really is no around that. The only thing you might be able to do is say that because the derivative only depends upon $x_j$ and finite sums are commutative we can express this as $a_{ij}x_j+C$ where the other terms are constant with respect to $x_j$ but that seems really sloppy to me. What is wrong with what you have written?

Comment: Dear @JohnDouma thank you for your time replying to me. The result should be $$ \frac{\partial x_i^{\prime}}{\partial x_j} = a_{i j}
$$ **NOT** $$ \frac{\partial x_i^{\prime}}{\partial x_j} =\sum_{j=1}^2 a_{i j} $$ I do not know how the summation sign can be eleminated in my result.

Comment: @Sha All of the derivatives in the sum should be zero except the $x_j$ term. Also, each of your $a_{ij}$ terms should have $x_i$s in them.

Comment: I think am getting it now, thank you @JohnDouma. I wish you consider posting an answer out of the several comments we had. None of the already existing two answers address the derivation in the general form, which I think is more powerful and can be of assistance of someone else in the future.

Comment: @JohnDouma I found this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2150558/910071 which is addressing the same exact problem I had. It is really very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you choose to represent the system of equations as a sum, it looks like this:

$$ x^{'}_i = \sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij}x_j $$

For example, in the two-dimensional case (N=2), it follows that:

$$ x^{'}_1 = a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 $$
$$ x^{'}_2 = a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 $$

As you can see, both systems are functions of $x_1$ and $x_2$, so we can differentiate each one of those in order to obtain the required $a_{ij}$. Lets see one of them:

$$  \frac{\partial x^{'}_1}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial (a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2)}{\partial x_1} = a_{11} $$

The same procedure is done for the rest of the $a_{ij}$ required cosines. Trying to generalize this, we can differentiate the sum with respect of $x_j$, it then looks as follow:

$$  \frac{\partial x^{'}_i}{\partial x_j} = a_{ij} $$

That's where it comes from :)

Answer (score 1):

You can verify-

$\frac{\partial x_1'}{\partial x_1}=a_{11},\frac{\partial x_1'}{\partial x_2}=a_{12},\frac{\partial x_2'}{\partial x_1}=a_{21}\ and\ \frac{\partial x_2'}{\partial x_2}=a_{22}$

Comment: these are from the equations for $x_1'\ and\ x_2'$ which you have given